# Use session object from PHP in Laravel 4.2 controller

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.2, I have declared a session:

```
session_start();
$code=rand(100000,999999);
$_SESSION["captcha"]=$code;
```

Then I want to get the data that I have stored, and use it in a Laravel controller to check if the user entered the right code before I enter it inside the database.

Here is my code:

```
public function store2()
{
    // i was trying to get the value
    // session_start();
    // $getsCapt = $_SESSION["captcha"];

    $rules = array(
        'username'     => 'required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/',
        'description'  => 'required|min:1|max:100|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/',
        'usertype'     => 'required|numeric'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('createsu')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } 
    else 
    {
        // store
        $su = new SystUser;
        $su->SystemUserTypeID       = Input::get('usertype');
        $su->SystemUserName         = Input::get('username');
        $su->SystemUserPassword     = 'changeme';
        $su->SystemUserDescription  = Input::get('description');
        $su->timestamps = false;
        $su->save();

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created system user!');
        return Redirect::to('createsu');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familar with laravel but I think you should use `$getsCapt = Session::get('captcha');` instead of `session_start();` and `$getsCapt = $_SESSION["captcha"];`.

Comment: thanks will try this too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you don't have to start session explicitly.

You can do something like:

**To Set In Session**

```
$captcha='whatever';
Session::put('captcha', $captcha);
```

**To Get From Session**

```
if(Session::has('captcha'){
    $captcha = Session::get('captcha');
}
```

Comment: can i use  `Session::put('captcha', $captcha)'` inside a php file? because i'am generating the value of $captcha on a PHP file

Comment: yes you can use it inside php file, best place would be in a controller.